# For any open subset $A\subseteq \mathbb{R}$, $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})=A$?

Tags: analysis

In the quiz of a class in MIT OCW, there is a T/F problem :

For any open subset $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$,  $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})=A$?

The hompage of the class also provided a answer, and I saw the answer of the above.

The answer is False, because (the writer said) $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})$ does not contain all isolated points of $A$.

But I think the reason is incorrect, because A is a open subset of $\mathbb{R}$.
(Every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ consists of interior points.)

Although the original answer of the above question may be False, but is the reason that writer said incorrect?

Comment: Yes, the reason is incorrect. If $A$ is open, then $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})$ contains all isolated points of $A$ (and for $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, there are none, but that's not important). $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})$ in general contains points of $\mathbb{R}\setminus A$, that's why the equality does not generally hold.

Comment: You and Daniel are correct.  In a question like this, a specific counterexample is probably better than an answer like the answerer of this question attempted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

False. $A=(0,1)\cup(1,2)$, $A$ is open, but $\overline{A}=[0,2]$ and $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})=(0,2)$. It may be the case that the real reason is, in fact, that $\operatorname{int}(\overline{A})$ may contain isolated points of the complement of $A$.

Comment: I think so, too. Thanks.

Comment: @JeongNam-ho Could you please provide the link to the MIT OCW website? I'm just curious about what this class is like.

Comment: There are many courses in the website. http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/ Just browse downward.

Comment: @JeongNam-ho Can you remember the actual course number this particular problem is from?

Comment: The name of the class is analysis and the above problem might be in the first quize.

Comment: @JeongNam-ho Found it, thank you!